# javascript sending data into a url

Tags: javascript

I  have tried this code for sending some information to a specific IP. That IP is a microcntroller that acts as a server.

However it sends the information to a page named with that IP not to that IP.

The code is written in JavaScript. What I should to do? Use post method or Xmlhttprequest and how to do that. I think my code is very simple:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function validateForm()
{
var x=document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value;
if (x==null || x=="")
  {
  alert("First name must be filled out");
  return false;
  }
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form name="myForm" action="192.168.1.250" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
First name: <input type="text" name="fname">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: for the record, try: <input required name="fname">

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the protocol

```
action="http://192.168.1.250"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you were wanting to send the User to that IP as well, then you would use POST. If actually you want to remain on the same page, send information - visa versa then indeed an AJAX call would be most sufficient. Below I use vanilla JavaScript instead of any JavaScript libraries, although using jQuery would provide you with some callbacks/helpers to make your code more stable.

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/atjBQ/3/

```
<script>
    /** 
     * Validate Form, else, Send Ajax
    **/
    function validateform() {
       var x = document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value;
        if ( x == null || x == "" ) { 
            alert( "First Name must be filled out" );  
            return false;
        }

        /** 
         * If POST
         *   use: xmlhttp.setRequestHeader(
         *           "Content-type", 
         *           "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
         *           );
        **/
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://192.168.1.250?q=" + x, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
        return false;
    }
</script>

<form name="myForm" id="myformtosend">
    <label for="fname">First name:</label><input type="text" name="fname" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

**With jQuery**:

```
/** 
 * Snippet Reference to: 
 * http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/   
**/

<script>
   $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "http://192.168.1.250",
     data: data,
     success: function() {
        /** Some Code **/
     }   
   });
</script>
```